Google one tap login. I am unable to retrieve profile picture for some of the user
const oauthClient = new OAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret);

    const response: LoginTicket = await oauthClient.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
    });

    const responsePayload = response.getPayload();


Token coming from frontend.

Here in responsePayload not able to get the profile_picture for some users. any help appreciate

You should include profile in your scopes
const scopes = ['openid', 'profile'];  

const oauthClient = new OAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret);

const response: LoginTicket = await oauthClient.verifyIdToken({
  idToken: token,
  audience: yourClientId,  
  scopes: scopes,
});

const responsePayload = response.getPayload();


Thank You @BugHunter for your response. Let me check with it.
